# Cloud project using gsuite

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-sheets-query

Now i have a number of seats for  some trip and guests reserve their seats by filling a  reservation form so i want to.  decrease number of  seats by rach reservation dynamically using app script code 
Execuse my english thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the [help documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the kind of thing you'll want to play with.

```
//assuming form returns number of seats reseved as SeatsReserved in namedValues object.  
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var lock=LockService.getScriptLock();
  var rs=Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('RemainSeats'));
  var remainingSeats=rs-e.namedValues.SeatsReserved;
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('RemainingSeats', remainingSeats);
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

And you'll need to be able to initialize RemainSeats

```
function initSeats(s){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('RemainSeats', s);
}
```

> > Note I haven't tested this, so write your own but now you know to look up ProptiesService, LockService and check out namedValues in the reference on Event Objects for Spreadsheets. Have fun.